# update sql command not executing correctly from vb code

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

In my application, I have a call for an update to a table on my database. I know that it is executing because I get a 1 returned when checking the number of rows affected but when I look on the DB the value is not updated - I have refreshed and still no update. Here is the code, `taskgrp_template` is type bit and `taskgrp_id` is type integer. Id is also set to the correct value, as the result of my tracepoint - results listed below code.

```
            mycmd.CommandText = "UPDATE p2_taskgroups SET TASKGRP_template = 1 WHERE TASKGRP_ID =" & id
            rowsChecked = mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Tracepoint result: the value of id is 55 and the value of templateCheck is 14 the number of rows affected was 1

Comment: Are you sure the connection string is pointing to the right database?

Comment: Have you tried running this query in SSMS?

Comment: Also have you tried debugging? What is the value of `id`? Also, look into parameterising your queries. http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: I am sure the connection string is pointed to the proper database, when debugging the value of id is correct

Comment: My suggestion is debug the code, put a breakpoint right at rowsChecked, inspect the value of the whole query with the id, and try to run it from SSMS. If you see no errors, your problem is probably the connection string as @Sparky mentioned

Comment: It would be helpful to see the entire block of code, too.  Are you running inside a using, or try-catch block? Are you using transactions?

Answer (score 0):

Just as a suggestion. You may also want to be sure your pointing to the right schema, just in case you have several schemas other than the "dbo."

Comment: after looking further into, connection string was the issue. Thank you.